# How to apply 3 conditions in formula field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying apply 3 conditions in formula field. but I'm to complete the requirement. My formula will be like this

```
IF(
    AND(
        CreatedById  = 'xxxxxx',
        ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c ,'Budget')
    ),
    year(EndDate__c) + 1,
    IF( 
        AND(
            CreatedById  = 'xxxxxx',
            NOT(ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c ,'Budget'))
        ),
        year(EndDate__c),
        Fore_Year__c
    )
)
```

Required result :(1) If created by id and scenerio = 'Budget' then Result will be Enddate+1, (2)If scenerio not equal to Budget then enddate or else (3)foreyear.

Could anybody can help me for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to revise the logic:

1) If CreatedById != 'xxx', then Fore_Year__c (it is your external if condition).

2) If CreatedById = 'xxx', then check Scenario__c.

```
IF (
    CreatedById = 'xxxxxx',
    IF (
        ISPICKVAL(Scenario__c ,'Budget'),
        year(EndDate__c) + 1,
        year(EndDate__c)
    ),
    Fore_Year__c
)
```

Comment: You could even take it one step further: `year(enddate__c) + if(ispickval(scenario__c,'Budget'),1,0)`